# jQuery Mobile is storing multiple instances of the same element in DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have three pages (each one is a HTML file) and all three pages has a footer:

```
    <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="single.html?id=" class="">Store</a></li>
                <li><a href="map.html?id=" class="">Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="info.html?id=" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Info</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

In order to fetch data from server or local storage, I add the entity ID to the URL using jQuery:

```
setFooter: function(id){
    $('footer li a').each(function(){
        var val = $(this).prop('href');
        $(this).prop('href', val + id);
    })
},
```

For the first page, everything is ok. For the second pages I have two instances of the footer and on the third page I get three instances.

Why is JQM adding multiple instances to DOM and how can I avoid this? I don't want to turn of caching, because it speeds up the page loading.

PS. this basically goes for all static content in a JQM Page. I don't get this with content gotten from Handlebars.js.

Comment: This is the nature of jQM navigation  http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation/ . It loads pages via AJAX into the existiing DOM (this allows page transitions, etc.), so your previous pages are still there. You can override this behavior:   http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation-linking-pages/

Comment: It's not a complete explanation but `$(this).prop('href')` will reflect the previous ID, so the IDs will append accumulatively. Rather than simply appending, you probably just need to replace the previous ID (if it exists).

Comment: @ezanker I know all this. But it doesn't solve my problem of duplicate content in DOM. roamer - I still have 3 x <footer> content - so on the 3rd page, it loops through 9 list elements.

Comment: Instead of $('footer li a') which finds every footer in the dom, Get the active page (http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-getActivePage) and find the footer within that page.

Comment: Can't use that `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization;` I do however have the name of the active page, but this doesn't work either: `$('#'+activePage+'footer li a').each()`

Comment: You need to do it inside of the appropriate jQM page event e.g. $(document).on("pagecreate", function(){ setFooter(); });